# wamp server not showing codeigniter css and jquery files

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter, wamp

I am using WAMP server version  . When I try to transfer the code to other wamp server on other pc and test the result only the html files are shown the others are not. CSS and other jQuery files are not shown. I have searched for this for two days before asking here. The code is a CodeIgniter code. I tested it in other way by moving other CodeIgniter code to other WAMP it works fine but this one doesn't. I have tested the code on my WAMP many times it works fine, but when I try to move it to other WAMP server it doesn't work. it only shows html.

Comment: Show some code? Plus, what do you mean "they are not shown"? Do you not get any errors?

Comment: i mean only the html part is displayed. the pages are displayed like they were written with pure html. no other thing

Comment: i didn't get  any errors.

Comment: This migh help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: Make sure you have set your base_url in config.php